# Getting points of polygons from a canvas

Tags: c#

*Implementing a WPF application in C# for Pixelsense*.

I'm having difficulties with finding the specific points where a polygon is placed on the screen in order to detect polygon overlap (which is next stage). In total, I can have 7 polygons in my application and below is the code where I try and get their points.

**What I thought the code would ideally do** is start a loop, create a polygon (shape 1) and then start the second loop, create another polygon (shape 2) and get both the shapes points and check for overlap. Then the second loop would proceed to check if another shape (shape 3) overlaps with shape 1 by getting its points and so on... So the first polygon would get checked against the other 6 polygons for an overlap hence the nested loop.

However, **what is happening currently** is whatever points the method picks for the first polygon, they are replicated for the second polygon as well. So it prints out a set of duplicate points for the two separate polygons and loops forever.

**I've been stuck on this for a while now, please please help me :)**

```
public void DefiningPolygonArea()
    {
        foreach (var polygonsCollection1 in this.PlayingCanvas.Children)
        {
            Polygon polygon1 = polygonsCollection1 as Polygon;
            if (polygon1 != null)
            {
                foreach (var polygonsCollection2 in this.PlayingCanvas.Children)
                {
                    Polygon polygon2 = polygonsCollection2 as Polygon;
                    if (polygon1 != polygon2 && polygon2 != null)
                    {
                        HelperMethods.PointCollectionsOverlap_Fast(getPoints(polygon1), getPoints(polygon2));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

private List<Point> getPoints(Polygon poly)
    {
        if (poly.Points.Count == 4)
        {
            var transform = poly.TransformToVisual(this.PlayingCanvas);

            Point point1 = transform.Transform(poly.Points[0]);
            Point point2 = transform.Transform(poly.Points[1]);
            Point point3 = transform.Transform(poly.Points[2]);
            Point point4 = transform.Transform(poly.Points[3]);

            area1.Add(point1);
            area1.Add(point2);
            area1.Add(point3);
            area1.Add(point4);
            Console.WriteLine("polygon with 4 points consists of: " + area1[0] + " , " + area1[1] + " , " + area1[2] + " , " + area1[3]);

        }
        else if (poly.Points.Count == 3)
        {
            var transform = poly.TransformToVisual(this.PlayingCanvas);

            Point point1 = transform.Transform(poly.Points[0]);
            Point point2 = transform.Transform(poly.Points[1]);
            Point point3 = transform.Transform(poly.Points[2]);

            area1.Add(point1);
            area1.Add(point2);
            area1.Add(point3);
            Console.WriteLine("polygon with 3 points consists of: " + area1[0] + " , " + area1[1] + " , " + area1[2]);
        }

        return area1;
    }
```

OUTPUT:

polygon with 4 points consists of: 713.345368087522,713.83644226973 ,     550.136522242161,724.044829935686 , 463.067512500796,641.78273862321 ,   626.276358346157,631.574350957254

polygon with 3 points consists of: 713.345368087522,713.83644226973 , 550.136522242161,724.044829935686 , 463.067512500796,641.78273862321

Comment: your loop is wrong. you ask for the children in first loop and get first item. then you ask for the same yet again with the same result in second loop.. of course it'll present with what you have :) I can attempt to give you a possible solution but it'd help more if you actually gave us a reproducible minimal sample. (Maybe dump a sample project with problem on github and link it here so we can give you a proper fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, your loop needs to do an exclusion like so:

```
foreach (var polygon1 in this.PlayingCanvas.Children.OfType<Polygon>())
    foreach (var polygon2 in this.PlayingCanvas.Children.OfType<Polygon>().Where(x => x != polygon1))
            HelperMethods.PointCollectionsOverlap_Fast(getPoints(polygon1), getPoints(polygon2));
```

> Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I now understand how I was not filtering at the loop itself. It's getting different points now but something does wrong with the values after a while (as it's looping forever currently). How can I stop it from looping if the object is at the same points and not moving to a new place on the canvas?

Comment: polygon with 4 points consists of: 382.04,636.94 , 501.04,615.31 , 525.06,747.46 , 406.07,769.09
polygon with 3 points consists of: 502.44,852.86 , 579.80,756.23 , 665.79,845.27




polygon with 3 points consists of: 502.44,852.86 , 579.80,756.23 , 665.79,845.27
polygon with 4 points consists of: 11049.04,11311.11 , 11167.98,11289.19 , 11192.32,11421.28 , 11073.37,11443.20

Comment: Sorry I've no idea, given how limited information I can glean from the question. The numbers don't really mean much to me. Perhaps you should create a new question with a minimal sample project that recreates your problem and post it on github so others can download and see the problem by clicking a link in your question. Good luck!

Comment: I'm using physical objects with tags (tangibles) on the pixelsense table so running a sample project doesn't do much without them in the picture :( Thank you for your time though :)